# How do I make List<string> as optional parameter?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Here is the program I am working on :

```
public class SESReqErrorIdAndArgs {

    public String errorIdentifier;
    public List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
 
    public  SESReqErrorIdAndArgs(String errorIdentifier,List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<>()){
        this.errorIdentifier = errorIdentifier;
        this.args = arguments;
    }
}
```

When I am calling method I want to make second argument as optional. I don't even want to pass it as null. The way I initialise arguments(second parameter) is wrong. What is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Write another overload.

Comment: Have you considered a varargs?  (ie `String...` for the second argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't support optional parameters. You can provide multiple signatures with different parameters, like this:

```
public SESReqErrorIdAndArgs(String errorIdentifier, List<String> arguments) {
    this.errorIdentifier = errorIdentifier;
    this.args = arguments;
}

public SESReqErrorIdAndArgs(String errorIdentifier) {
    this(errorIdentifier, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Note that (1) there's no point in assigning a `new ArrayList<>()` in your `args` initializer, as it will always be immediately discarded, and (2) it's typically best to make a defensive copy of items passed in this way, so this is likely better (since Java 10):

```
public SESReqErrorIdAndArgs(String errorIdentifier, List<String> arguments) {
    this.errorIdentifier = errorIdentifier;
    this.args = List.copyOf(arguments);
}

public SESReqErrorIdAndArgs(String errorIdentifier) {
    this(errorIdentifier, Collections.emptyList());
}
```

Finally, depending on your use case varargs *might* be a better option:

```
public SESReqErrorIdAndArgs(String errorIdentifier, String... arguments) {
    this.errorIdentifier = errorIdentifier;
    this.args = List.of(arguments);
}
```